# safe(st) way rename a delphi Project

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Im sure this will be a simple one but have a project that started as a test.
When it was created it was saved as "Project2.dpr"

Now the test is no longer a 'test', i would like to change the projects name to something more meaningful.

whats the best way to do this?

Any issues with just changing the file name and the Program line to the new name? i.e.

meaningful.dpr

```
Program meaningful;
```

Note:Delphi 7 if it matters

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just do "Save Project as" from the file menu in Delphi giving it the name you want and, later on when you feel like, remove the Project2.* files from your folder as they are not needed anymore.

Comment: You will want to do it this way because it will change the identifier in the files as well as the file names.

Comment: Yup, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 19):

FYI: Starting with Delphi 8 you can simply right-click the project in the project manager and select "Rename" (or simply press F2). This has the benefit over the "Save As" approach that you don't end up with a copy.

(sorry, no Delphi 7 - thanks to Lars for the update)

Comment: Not possible in Delphi 7. But in Delphi 8 and higher you can. I prefer this even over the Save Project as, since you don't create a copy.

Comment: Also, when renaming, you can use ..\ or <foldername>\ to move the project (and even more convenient: units/forms) to move the files to different folders.

Comment: I just "saved project as" in delphi 7 (With Build 8.1 patch)